# Files in Watch Directory being locked while using DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

I have been monitoring files in a directory on the network. I had initially used FileWatcher to monitor them. I found that the files were being locked while using FileWatcher so I changed my implementation to use DirectoryInfo to watch for newly arrived and deleted files in the directory that I am watching. It seems while using DirectoryInfo also, the files in the watch directory are getting locked thereby preventing the files from being deleted by another application after downloading the files. My watch application is a windows service.

Could anybody tell me if they have faced issues and if they have, how you have been resolve it ?

Thanks,

Comment: " I found that the files were being locked while using FileWatcher" - seems unlikely....

Comment: are you processing the files while monitoring through filewatcher. you need to close the file handles gracefully in your application.

Comment: post your code - what do you do when you have new file?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that whatever is creating/updating the files is done? If not, the file will be locked.

Comment: There is a process A that generates 2 files (one of size 1KB;the other of size 67MB) and puts it in a n/w folder. These files are downloaded and later deleted by another process B after 4 to 5 hours. What my application does is, it checks the folder from the time the file arrives till the time the file is deleted and if the files are deleted, the application sends out a notification that the files have been deleted. What I found out was process B was able to download and delete the file of a smaller size but the larger file always had issues with deletion. I'm not processing any of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Even though FileWatcher is supposed to work on UNC shares I've had numerous problems doing so. Since your issue is not time-critical I'd create a Thread that just checks if the files are present, Sleeps a few seconds the loops until the files are gone at which time your alert is sent.

NB: Running as a service requires the running user to have network privileges on the remote share as well.

Update: Just did a quick test on our network. Client running Windows 7 server running Windows 2008 R2. Added several files, both small and large to the share. Did not have any problems deleting the files while the code was running. Even without the Thread.Sleep

```
        bool filesDeleted = false;

        while (!filesDeleted)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\path\");
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                DateTime created = file.CreationTime;
                string fileName = file.Name;

                //Do what every you need to check if the two files are still there
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

        //Send alert
```

Comment: That is how the application runs.. Checks for the files, sleeps , checks for the files again. The windows service has network privileges and I am able to successfully find out that one of the files have been deleted. However, the application which deletes the files is not able to delete the larger of the 2 files. There appears to be some lock placed on the file while the watcher application is run. Does "finfFileList = DirectoryInfo.getFiles()" on the watch directory followed by a subsequent access to "finfFileList.creationtime" by any chance place a lock on the file that I am watching ?

Comment: Ah sorry. I though you used the FileSystemWather class. I don't think it should not place any locks on them, but indexing service or antivirus might scan the files. I've had similar problems deleting large ISO image files. In my case removing the "allow files and folder to be indexed" property on the folders (advanced attributes) fixed it.

Comment: When the watcher application is not running, the files are able to be downloaded and deleted. It is only when the watcher application runs and watches the directory, it appears that locks are placed on the file and the file cannot be deleted by the application downloading the file and we have to actually manually delete the file from the folder later.

Comment: Why are you checking finfFileList.creationtime? Does it matter for you when the files were created? Your description only says to send alert when two specific files are gone. How to you identify them in the first place?

Comment: The initial application also checked for file arrival and stored the creation time of the files. Well, I can do without the creation time. I was just curious about the creation time though. Well, I take a list of the files that are in the watch directory and periodically get the list of files in the directory and compare with what I have which gives me the list of files that have newly arrived and those that have been deleted.

Comment: The watch application is exactly like your code snippet except that the servershare path is got just once at the beginning of the application. Also wanted to add that both the files in the directory being watched are being FTP'ed.